# Azure datafactory v2 Linkedservice build

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am using the following JSON template

```
{
     "properties": {
         "type": "AzureStorage",
         "typeProperties": {
             "connectionString": {
                 "type": "SecureString",
                 "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<accountname>;AccountKey=<accountkey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
             }
         }
     },
     "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService"
 }
```

from the URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-powershell#get-storage-account-name-and-account-key
 to create an Azure storage Linked service.
Rather than hard-coding the Account name and the key is it possible to pass it as a parameter to the PowerShell cmdlet

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService
```

I am trying to build a PowerShell script to automate the deployment

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but do you want to dynamically extract the azure account name and account key?

are you automating this  for many environments? in my cause i am using azure DevOps and Azure Key Vault to pass the required parameters per environment (Dev, Test, and Production), there is a very nice step-by-step guide that automates the deployment of ADF here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

You don't have to hard-code the keys, passwords, etc. but you have to have them specified in Azure Key Vault and link this to ADF

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/secure-credential-management-using-azure-key-vault-and-data-factory/

So, for example for an Azure Data Lake Store  you can specify something like this

```
{
    "name": "linked_service_adls",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "typeProperties": {
            "dataLakeStoreUri": "https://YOURADLSNAME.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1",
            "servicePrincipalId": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
            "servicePrincipalKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "linked_service_kv_general",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "adls-webapi-principalKey"
            },
            "tenant": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
            "subscriptionId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "resourceGroupName": "rg-whatever"
        }
    }
}
```

Where the servicePrincipalKey does not have to be hard-coded and gets dynamically extracted from your Azure Key Vault ( using "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret" and the secret name "adls-webapi-principalKey" )and in Azure DevOps you can specify the parameters values for service PRincipal ID , tenant, subscriptionID, etc for every target environment, which at the same time you can extract also from AKV (Azure Key Vault), I know that your use case is Powershell oriented but if that's the case you would still need some sort of config file to pull of these values, and of course it is not a good idea to version control config files so they have to live somewhere, I stronlgy recommend the AKV/Azure Devops approach. Hope this helps